# How to whitelist_gpl-3 for only one development image recipe?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I use `INCOMPATIBLE_LICENSE = "GPL-3.0 LGPL-3.0 AGPL-3.0"` to restrict GPLv3 packages from my production build, but I want to include gdb in a development build, `image-dev`. I can whitelist it in local.conf with `WHITELIST_GPL-3.0_append = " gdb"`, but this would allow someone to add it to the production build. I tried using `WHITELIST_GPL-3.0_append_pn-image-dev = " gdb"`. I can see that it sets the `WHITELIST_GPL-3.0` variable correctly, but I think it sets it after bitbake needed it because gdb is marked incompatible.

Also, I'd like to set this in the distro config or somewhere version controlled, i.e. not local.conf.

Comment: Not sure if it's possible to do without creating a separate distro for your image as those values are distro-wide, I think.